# The probability of the matrix $A = (a_{ij})_{i,j\leq n}$ for $a_{i,j}\sim \text{Bernoulli}(\rho)$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices

I have the next problem:

Let $A=(a_{i,j})_{1\leq i,j\leq n}\in\mathcal{M}_{n,n}(\{0,1\})$ such that $a_{i,j}\sim \text{Bernoulli}(\rho)$ for all $i,j=1,\dots,n$. How can I calculate the probability that $ A $ is an invertible matrix?

*For example:* Setting $n = 3$, to simplify the reasoning I had thought of studying $a_{i,j}$ for $i \geq j$, have:
\begin{equation}
    A =
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1&a&b\\
        0&1&c\\
        0&0&1\\
    \end{pmatrix}\quad\forall a,b,c\in\{0,1\}
\end{equation}
is invertible.

Comment: it's akin to counting how many of the $2^n$ $0,1$ matrices are invertible and I doubt there is a simple closed formula. As $n\to\infty$, you can probably argue that the probabilitiy goes to zero by some simple bounding.

Comment: This paper should be helpful for you: https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.06553